# Is there any effective way to remove a certain index from an arrayList in java?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, arraylist

I have been trying and googling for hours. But I cannot come to a solution.
My ArrayList = "1+2*6/2". Every time an operator matches, it should remove the before and after the index of the operator and replace the index with the result. My code removes the before and after indices but gives exceptions whenever try to replace or remove the index.

So, the List = "1 + 2 * 6 / 2";
After operation it should look like, List = "1 + 2 * 3;
But it gives exceptions .

My code:

```
package inheritance;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputs = "1 + 3 * 6 / 2";
        String[] splits = inputs.split(" ");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(splits);
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(list);


        int result = 0;
        int len = list1.size() - 1;


        for (int i = 0 ; i<=len; i++) {

            if (list1.get(i).equals("+")) {
                result = Integer.parseInt(list1.get(i - 1)) + Integer.parseInt(list1.get(i + 1));
                list1.remove(i - 1);
                list1.remove(i);
                list1.remove(i+1);
                list1.set(i + 1, String.valueOf(result));
                len = len - 2;

            }

        }

        System.out.println("List: " + list1);
        System.out.println(result);


    }


}
```

I have tried the decrease order loop too. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "remove an index"? You mean shorten the list by one element, and remove the element at that specific index, or just set that value to null?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: FYI: easy way to delete a range of a list: `list.subList(from, toExclusive).clear()` - see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) for details (and note that `set()` does not **add** an element to the list, it replaces one)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with your current approach, most fundamental of them is that an array is not the right data structure for parsing an arithmetic expression and evaluating arbitrary parts of it.

Even if you managed to do it correctly somehow, removing arbitrary elements from an  array is an `O(n)` operation, so this can become extremely slow.

As to your current code, the problem (ignoring the more fundamental ones), is that you change the structure of the array by removing an element, but still operate on it as if nothing had changed.

```
                list1.remove(i - 1);
                list1.remove(i);
                list1.remove(i+1);
```

When you remove element `i-1`, element `i` will be at index `i-1`, so removing `i` after that, is effectively removing the *old* `i+1`, etc. This messes up your results and chances are high that you go out of bounds.

Comment: I have just started android development. I don’t know ds & algo yet. I was trying to make a calculator. Do you think I should learn ds & algo first? If yes, suggest me some tips and resources for practising  to get better at it. Thanks